# Fuzzy CSV column matching

Tags: python, csv

I'm parsing a lot of `.csv` files right now, and I'm running into issues where one `.csv` will identify, say, a column that holds the name of a candidate running for office with the header `candidate_name`, while another will use `CANDIDATE_FULL_NAME`.

I'm updating dictionaries with the results of the columns like this, except constantly changing the row[value] for each different header.

```
dict.update({
    'candidate': row['column_header']
```

Is there a way to fuzzy match this? Preferably something that I can use almost drop-in so that I don't have to set up a class/method that regex tests each column for its similarity.

I already set up a class that tests to match a value to a list of values, but I feel as if this is something that I won't have to write myself. Unfortunately, my google-fu has returned nothing.

I'd use the column number, but unfortunately the columns aren't always in the same order. Additionally, I can't alter the original `.csv` files (or else I'd *definitely* normalize them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No "fuzzy" matching built-in to `pandas` as far as I know. If there is some common denominator, e.g. the word "name" is only and always in the column that contains the candidate's name, you could use it to rename the name column. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fuzzymatch(df, string, stname):

    for col in df.columns:
        if col.lower().find(string) > -1:
            df.rename(columns={col:stname}, inplace=True)
            break

    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({"CANDIDATE_NAME_HERE": ["Ted","Fred","Sally","John","Jane"], "B": [20, 30, 10, 40, 50], "C": [32, 234, 23, 23, 42523]})
#pd.read_csv('filename.csv') will load your csv file

string = 'name'
stname = 'candidate_name'

df = fuzzymatch(df, string, stname)
print(df)

    B      C candidate_name
0  20     32            Ted
1  30    234           Fred
2  10     23          Sally
3  40     23           John
4  50  42523           Jane
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went with a solution where I test the first row of my `.csv` file with some regular expressions to find the column I want instead. Constructing a class that does this allows me to 'fuzzy match' more parts of my code and cuts down on its size (and makes it more readable!). But thanks again!